# Is leaking information ever acceptable if it may affect somebody elses professional career?

Tags: confidentiality

Complete re-edit to avoid speculation:

An employee lied to a new customer completely behind the back of the PM/leads/management that he/she was not being allocated (he/she actually was 100% allocated) and therefore available for a new project which he/she liked better. Nobody knew about this conversations, the new customer expects delivery and the old team is stretched thin by this (and the old customer may have some projects which run late, potentially causing financial damage). There are circumstances which prevent management level from communicating clearly, but I was one of colleagues in the team to whom she bragged about how great this move was, and how cool it was to lie also to PM and management.

Would it be appropriate to have a clarifying conversation with the technical side at the old/new customer (both in one company), to clearly state that they should be very careful about promises of this employee in the future, pointing out that he/she intentionally lied, even if this information may damage the employees further career in the projects at the customer? Up to now our team/management was playing nice and took the blame under "there was some miscommunication".

Comment: To achieve what? I think this is very shaky. Objectively proven? In whose opinion? They were reprimanded by HR? Will this person be fired for cause? If not, and this leaking will cause this person not to be hired at their next company then it seems to me that this gets very close to libel.

Comment: If it is not your information then you should not leak it.

Comment: to stratify the professional relationship with the business partner which was harmed by the person intentionally miscommunicating about a project staffing and progress to serve their own interests.

Comment: @onnoweb: for libel/defamation the information must be false. The person stating the fact proudly to the fact of lying of two colleagues and leaving proven track record by emails is objective.

Comment: @SolarMike: The statement "this person did not act on the teams behalf and exceeded his/her authority" it's hardly personal information.

Comment: If this is about trying to save the relationship with the business partner then you don't do it by just informing (I mean, leaking to) the partner that you had this rogue employee. You do that in a proper meeting, acknowledging that the project was not managed well, is off track and here are the actions your company is taking to correct.

Comment: Many systems of ethics consider what happens when "this action is not good, but not engaging in this action is also not good - so now what?" Most would suggest that you should generally keep privileged information under wraps, unless there is an incredibly compelling reason not to (greater evil). If you find out someone is involved in the human slave trade, abusing children, or faking provocation for international war, being sworn to secrecy should not stop you from finding a way to speak out - you aren't a cleric taking confession. But it should be a damn good reason, and expect to suffer.

Comment: @Sascha I did not limit my statement to personal information... You might if you wish...

Comment: To be clear, are you asking if YOU should leak the information to the client?  Or if your COMPANY should leak the information?

Comment: it is unclear what are you asking. Who will you leak it? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: The various violations you have mentioned might all have very different answers. "Knowledge of application at other companies"??? Really? That's not even a problem, it's even expected. "Gross case of non loyalty" sounds extremely subjective. This will probably come down to "It depends on the circumstances." Are you prepared to share the circumstances?

Comment: I think this, more than any other question I've read, is where the OP is really really really hoping for one specific answer.

Comment: @Aaron: an employee lied to a new customer completely behind the back of the PM and leads that he/she was not being allocated (he/she actually was 100% allocated) and therefore available for a new project which he/she liked. Nobody knew about this conversations, the new customer expects delivery and the old team is stretched thin by this. There are circumstances which prevent management level from communicating clearly, but I was one of colleagues in the team to whom she bragged about how great this move was, and how cool it was to lie also to PM and management.

Answer (score 8):

It's unlikely that there will be significant benefit to attempting to disparage this person.

If you inform your customers that this person acted alone, your customers will wonder why there was not enough oversight to prevent this.

If you inform companies that may be looking to employ the person, then it will become a case of their word against yours and the companies may question your motivations and truthfulness.  If these companies are current or potential customers, then the above holds doubly: why was there no oversight to prevent this and why is there no oversight preventing backstabbing colleagues from spreading stories.

Your best course of action is to be glad the bad apple is gone, ensure you and your company deliver good quality results moving forward and avoid interacting with that person in a professional capacity in the future.